# Factors of $\gcd(2^{2^n}-1,3^{2^n}-1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Gerry Myerson [examined the sequence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70371/greatest-common-divisor-of-a2n-1-and-b2n-1/70389#70389) $$a_n=\gcd(2^{2^n}-1,3^{2^n}-1)$$

I am interested in the factors of $a_n$.

Since $2^{2^n}-1$ is the product of first $n-1$ Fermat numbers, and $3^{2^n}-1=2 \prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}{3^{2^k}+1}$, factors of $a_n$ will be in the intersection.

What is currently known to me about the factors:

For $n<20$, the factors are Fermat Primes.

For $20 \le n \le 36$, $a_n=5 \cdot 17 \cdot 257 \cdot 65537 \cdot 13631489$.
$a_{39}$ is divisible by  $ 2^{41} \cdot 3+1$.

Search in the intersection of [known Fermat factors](http://www.prothsearch.net/fermat.html) and [known factors of generalized fermat numbers GFN'(3)=$\frac{3^{2^m}+1}{2}$](http://www1.uni-hamburg.de/RRZ/W.Keller/GFN03.html) showed 19 factors of $a_n$. The format is pair $(k,n)$ with $p=k\cdot2^n+1$:

[(3, 41), (21, 41), (9, 67), (5, 127), (3, 209), (7, 320), (29, 4727), (9, 9431), (81, 12189), (81, 28285), (7, 95330), (3, 157169), (3, 213321), (3, 303093), (3, 382449), (9, 461081), (243, 495732), (3, 2145353), (3, 2478785)]

To verify the above, work modulo the factor.

Computing the actual gcd for $n=33$ will require about 12G of RAM and will take about 7 hours in a [C++ ntl implementation](http://paste.ubuntu.com/645809/).

Would it be possible some clever trick to reduce the memory requirement, hopefully finding unknown Fermat factor?

Another question are infinitely many primes expected to divide $a_n$?

Comment: You won't find all factors in this way, but you could simply calculate modulo some power of two times a small odd factor plus 1, as these are anyway the most likely prime factors to show up.

Comment: @jp I suppose they already did what you propose for Fermat factors, so for know I resort to searching in the subset of Fermat factors - it is not very fast for me assuming I am doing it right (just testing the pseudo primality of the largest Fermat factors might take more than 10 hours IMHO...)

Comment: @jp How do you formally define **small** odd?

Comment: @joro: I don't define small *formally*. I would just start with $3$ and increase it at will. Is your goal to find Fermat factors or to find the gcd?

Comment: @jp Thank you! I am interested in both the gcd and the fermat factors. I completely agree with your method. AFAICT the gcd is divisible by only fermat factors. A lot of people spent a lot of time searching for fermat factors (mainly by your method) so I just reuse their computations checking the found factors, which is not as fast as it may seem.

Comment: @joro: I just looked at your link "known Fermat factor". Now I understand whom you mean with "they" in your first comment ;-). Just forget, what I commented...

Comment: @jp Probably I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: @joro: In your 2nd edit you removed your question.

Comment: @jp Would it be easy to prove $a_n$ doesn't become constant after some term?

Comment: @joro: For me **no** ;-).

Comment: @jp appears to me sufficient condition $p$ to divide $a_n$ is the multiplicative orders of 2 and 3 in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ to be both powers of two. If there are infinitely many primes of the form $3 \cdot 2^k+1$ they might be good candidates (as suggested experimentally). If $k \equiv 0 \mod 3$ then 3 will have the right order and 2 will have right order with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. This well may be wrong.